# Can't move scrollbar inside of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an issue. I'm using [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) plugin for custom scrollbars, and have set it up to show up in iframe but I can't scroll on neither the Y or X axis. The content just doesn't load. (?) I have used [this](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/examples/iframe_example.html) example and set the height to 100%. This is what I got so far:

```
<div id="iframecontainer" style="height: 100%; position: relative; overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;">
<iframe src="http://imgur.com/a/LqmeJ?gallery" scrolling="no" width="1000" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

//I use this javascript code to run the scrollbar plugin.
//I also include its files in <head> tag.

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#iframecontainer').mCustomScrollbar({
            theme:"minimal-dark", scrollInertia: 0, axis:"yx"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to add that I can't delete the scroller, doing so would ruin my design. Maybe there's an other way to include the file? I'm using iframes so I can switch the websites using a menu buttion.

Comment: perhaps because you set `scrolling="no"`?

Comment: If I set scrolling to "yes" it will make my custom scrollbar disappear, and I want to avoid that. I found a workaround for now, I set height to 99999px and I can scroll websites endlessly, but that's okay, because everything else works.

Comment: maybe some elements are laying in front of the `.iframecontainer`? Or what do you mean can't move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for now, I set height to 99999px and I can scroll websites endlessly, but that's okay, because everything else works. It seems that there is no other way to fix that.